# Items are not pinned to Windows server 2012's start menu

Tags: install4j

My existing installer works properly for Windows 7. It shows all items properly under start menu.

In Windows server 2012, only "uninstaller.exe" is shown pinned under "start menu". I expect all other items - internet shortcut, folder and .bat file to show up pinned as well.

Comment: Please send the log file (.install4j\installation.log) and the install4j project file to support@ej-technologies.com